# sp_send_dbmail runs and sends mail when run in query window, runs successfully in agent job but not mail is sent?

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I have stored procedure that calls sp_send_dbmail. If I run it from a query window in SSMS it runs ok and sends the mail. If it runs in an agent job, the job reports success, but no mail is sent. What gives?

Comment: The following article details how to grant the appropriate permissions to allow SQL Agent to send dbmail: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190606(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190606%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) This is a decent walkthrough detailing how to configure dbmail from a reusable script: [LINK](http://sqltidbits.com/scripts/configure-database-mail-reusable-script-sql-job-alerts)

Comment: Thanks...followed it most of the way, but this instruction doesn't make sense to me. "3.Create a Database Mail profile for the SQL Server Agent service account to use and add the user to the DatabaseMailUserRole in the msdb database."

Comment: I create a profile, and then it starts talking about a user. By user does it mean the database mail profile I created, or the sql server agent service?

Comment: Also, how do I set the profile to the default profile in msdb? I don't see where to do that anywhere...

Comment: Have you enabled the profile in the SQL Agent? Right-click SQL Server Agent > Properties > Alert System > Enable Mail Profile

Comment: You can set to public and default in the Configure Database Mail wizard. Also, restart Agent after making such changes

Comment: And, by user it means the user context the SQL Agent is running under. A public profile will not need the granular permission however.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a T-SQL query within the msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail stored procedure, please make sure the user used to executed the job is a valid login in database engine.